# HDF5 error no file name specified, Crashes in Boost

Tags: boost, makefile, maya, hdf5, alembic

I'm trying to build a source code on OSX but getting the following error when running it. It seems to be related HDF5 but I've got no clue how to fix that since the Linux and Win built of this source code already works fine.

```
Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.15-patch1) thread 5963292672:

#000: H5F.c line 435 in H5Fis_hdf5(): no file name specified major: Invalid arguments to routine
minor: Out of range
```

And a crash happens right after that here

```
CRASHED in boost::re_detail::basic_regex_parser<char, signal caught: SIGSEGV -- Invalid memory reference

boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::parse_extended at 00:00:00
```

I built HDF5 (hdf5-1.8.5-patch1) based on this [page](https://github.com/alembic/alembic/blob/master/doc/HDF5-howtobuild.txt) , plus, I added the following compiler flags to the already mentioned flags on that page before building it. Is there any wrong with those?

```
ENV.append "CXXFLAGS", "-std=c++03 -stdlib=libstdc++"
ENV.append "CFLAGS", "-stdlib=libstdc++"
ENV.append "LDFLAGS", "-stdlib=libstdc++ -lstdc++"
ENV["CXX"] = "/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++"
```

Does anyone know how I can fix that error/crash on Mac?

Thanks.